# how to make a WCF Service that is only HTTP as also HTTPS without creating new or breaking existing clients

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, https, wcf-security

I have a WCF Service that is using basicHttpBinding. That is exposed as HTTP to many clients.

Now our requirement is to expose this service as HTTPS to few new clients while we shouldn't break existing clients that consume over http.

I came across detecting the type of security programmatically and then expose, but is there any other better and easy way for me to do that? Just with the endpoints configuration etc?

I am fairly new to these areas, please help with an example

Comment: Create a different endpoint and behavior for httpsEndpoint

Comment: try to create another endpoint using Transport security and assign a http and https base address in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a better solution as you mentioned with configuration which I have done two days ago for some our services.

Add `basicHttpBinding` like below:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding allowCookies="true" openTimeout="00:00:10" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="200000000" maxStringContentLength="200000000" />
    <security mode="None" />
  </binding>
  <binding name="secureBasicHttpBinding">
    <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
    </security>
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

and service end point:

```
<service  name="ServiceName">
  <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="Rest.Behavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="System.Data.Services.IRequestHandler">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost"/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="Rest.Behavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureBasicHttpBinding" contract="your service contract">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Service.svc"/>
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>
</service>
```

and in IIS you just need add valid certificate and enable it, `https` use `secureBasicHttpBinding` and `http` use default basic `httpConfiguration`.

I have tested it before an now some client using that service in `https` some other are using `http`.

Tip:

In local mode there is error while hosting `WCF` services by above config so I came to this conclusion to put that config in `release` mode not in `debug` mode, because the `https` is enable on working server.

so in `release` config have something like (to be transferred after publishing):

```
<service  name="ServiceName" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="Replace">
  <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="Rest.Behavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="System.Data.Services.IRequestHandler">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost"/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="Rest.Behavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureBasicHttpBinding" contract="your service contract">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://localhost/AAA/Service.svc"/>
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>
</service>
```